# Rebuild a compromised cluster on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nodes, cluster-computing, data-loss

I'm using an elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes (one of them is a master and the other two are master-eligible). Unfortunately, all of them have been stopped at the same time and after restarting them I'm encountering 2 different problems:

1. The cluster is not able to elect a master node anymore (logs from my linux machine below):

```
[2024-01-08T12:07:34,186][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [masterNodeES1] master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires at least 2 nodes with ids from [Wp2ThiNCT-xpIskc0FTITg, 7PZ-SP5usdoKrL4tjfSMgA, nLFU0ydhTgsVItQNFL3T2n], have discovered [{masterNodeES1}{7PZ-SP5usdoKrL4tjfSMgA}{Z2B4Rja5TneDDm7N6fGYjQ}{<ip_master_node>}{<ip_master_node>:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=4046721024, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}] which is not a quorum; discovery will continue using [<ip_node_2>:9300, <ip_node_3>:9300] from hosts providers and [{masterNodeES1}{7PZ-SP5usdoKrL4tjfSMgA}{Z4B4Rji5TzeDDe7N5fBYjQ}{<ip_master_node>}{<ip_master_node>:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=4046721024, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}] from last-known cluster state; node term 102018, last-accepted version 13415 in term 11968
```

2. I'm not able to query my cluster anymore because of failed authentication error. The logs below from my linux machine are generated by curl -u user:password -XGET '<master_node_ip>:9200/_cat/indices?pretty':

```
{ "error" : { "root_cause" : [ { "type" : "security_exception", "reason" : "failed to authenticate user [elastic]", "header" : { "WWW-Authenticate" : "Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8"" } } ], "type" : "security_exception", "reason" : "failed to authenticate user [elastic]", "header" : { "WWW-Authenticate" : "Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8"" } }, "status" : 401 }
```

Since I can't query the database, I can't specify the elasticsearch version (it could be 5.x.x), but anyway I noticed that elasticsearch-reset-password Tool is not present in my /bin folder. **I just want to know if is there a way to restore my cluster without losing data that are inside their nodes**. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bin/x-pack/users](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/users-command.html) command in ESv5 or [bin/elasticsearch-users](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/users-command.html) command for ESv6 and onwards.

**Elasticsearch version 5**

```
bin/x-pack/users useradd test -p test -r superuser
```

**Elasticsearch version 6 and onwards**

```
bin/elasticsearch-users useradd test -p test -r superuser
```

**test it**

```
curl -k 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty' -u test:test
curl -k 'https://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty' -u test:test
```

After create the user you can send curl request to **only** **localhost**. BUT if the `.security` index shards are not available you will get the same `security_exception` error. If it not works, check your elasticsearch logs, make sure all nodes are up and running and find a specific logs that can cause the issue.

To diagnose the issue:

1. Check network - let's try `telnet` the master2 from master1. `telnet ip_node_2 9300`

*Question: Did you lost any master node disks?*

Comment: Thanks for your reply Musab. Ok, then I might have ES6 since bin/elasticsearch-users works. Anyway, when launching the curl, Node1 give me the same exception, and the other two nodes return me a "master_not_discovered_exception". Every node is up and running but the unique message I could see in logs is the one that I mentioned in the first point of my post. This message appears about every 30 seconds in my logs in every single node

Comment: You're welcome I updated my answers with a diagnose recommendation and question.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately telnet is not working, it says "connection timed out" . No, I didn't: I just snapshotted, terminated and rebooted on a new instance every node of the cluster (one at a time), but I forgot to restart elasticsearch service in node2 before terminate node3 and then 2 of 3 nodes were unreachable at the same time

Comment: Thanks a lot Musab, I just had to update a firewall rule on 9300 port because ips have changed and they were not be able to communicate through this port anymore. Thank you again man

Comment: You're welcome @sicdb, happy to hear it fixed :)